# ListView in a Popup with EditText Issue in Android

Tags: android, xml, listview, baseadapter

I am having an issue with scrolling of ListView in a Popup. I have an activity that has a dialog theme so that it can open up as a popup. The Popup should contain EditText at the bottom and the remaining area above it should be the ListView. When the activity is started it should start with keypad open & focus on EditText.

Issue: ListView doesn't scroll when keypad is open.

Below is my activity code:

```
public class CommentsActivity extends Activity{
private InputMethodManager imm;
private String commentCount;
private ShopPirateDatabase db;
private ArrayList<CommentsBean> commentsList = new ArrayList<CommentsBean>();
@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.comments_layout);
 imm = (InputMethodManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
 db=new ShopPirateDatabase(this);
 if(getIntent().hasExtra("count")){
        commentCount=getIntent().getExtras().getString("count");
    }
 ListView lvMyComments=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvMyComments);
 lvMyComments.setVisibility(View.GONE);
 final Button btnPost=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPost);
 btnPost.setVisibility(View.GONE);
 etAddComment=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etAddComment);
 RelativeLayout progressLayout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.progressLayout);
 progressLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 TextView tvNoComments=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvNoComments);
 tvNoComments.setVisibility(View.GONE);
 imm.showSoftInput(etAddComment, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
 if(Integer.parseInt(commentCount) > 0){
        getCommentsFromDb();
        if(commentsList!=null && commentsList.size() > 0){
            progressLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tvNoComments.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            lvMyComments.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            CommentsAdapter commentsAdapter = new CommentsAdapter(
                    CommentsActivity.this, commentsList);
            lvMyComments.setAdapter(commentsAdapter);
        }
    } else{
        progressLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        tvNoComments.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        lvMyComments.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
private void getCommentsFromDb() {
    db.openDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.getComments();
    if (c != null) {
        commentsList = null;
        commentsList = new ArrayList<CommentsBean>();

        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

                CommentsBean mBeanClass = new CommentsBean();
                mBeanClass
                        .setCommentText(c.getString(c
                                .getColumnIndex(db.KEY_COMMENT_TEXT)));
                mBeanClass
                        .setCommentedDate(c.getString(c
                                .getColumnIndex(db.KEY_COMMENT_DATE)));
                mBeanClass
                        .setCommentedBy(c.getString(c
                                .getColumnIndex(db.KEY_COMMENT_USER)));

                commentsList.add(mBeanClass);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    c.close();
    db.closeDatabase();
   }
}
```

comments_layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/commentsBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_5"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_2"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_5" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPost"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/margin_35"
        android:background="@color/coupon_color"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_7"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin_15"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/margin_15"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_7"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_2"
        android:text="Post"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/normal_textsize" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etAddComment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_2"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btnPost"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_2"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_5"
        android:hint="@string/comment_hint" />

</RelativeLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvMyComments"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_5"
    android:divider="@color/home_bg_color"
    android:dividerHeight="@dimen/divider_height"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:visibility="gone" >
</ListView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/progressLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/commentsBox"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_10"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_10" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pBarComments"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/circular_progress_bar" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvWaitComments"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/pBarComments"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_5"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_5"
        android:text="Loading comments..."
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/small_textsize" />
</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvNoComments"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/etAddComment"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_15"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_25"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="No comments have been posted for this offer"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="@dimen/normal_textsize"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

CommentsAdapter.java

```
public class CommentsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;
private ArrayList<CommentsBean> mArrayList = new ArrayList<CommentsBean>();

public CommentsAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<CommentsBean> arrayList) {
    this.context = ctx;
    this.mArrayList = arrayList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mArrayList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View view;
    view = null;
    convertView = null;
    if (convertView == null) {

        view = new View(context);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_comments, null);

        TextView commentText = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.commentText);
        TextView postedDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.postedDate);
        TextView userName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.userName);

        commentText.setText(mArrayList.get(position).getCommentText());
        userName.setText(" - " + mArrayList.get(position).getCommentedBy());
        String dt = mArrayList.get(position).getCommentedDate();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date d = null;
        try {
            d = sdf.parse(dt);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        String convertedDate = null;
        convertedDate = sdf1.format(d);

        postedDate.setText(convertedDate);

    }
    return view;
  }
}
```

list_comments.xml

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/cmtIcon"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_25"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_25"
    android:src="@drawable/comment_list_icon"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_5"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_5"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/commentText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_10"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/cmtIcon"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_5"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="@dimen/normal_textsize" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/postedDate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/commentText" 
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/cmtIcon"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_10"       
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_5"
    android:text="Posted on"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="@dimen/small_textsize" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/userName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/postedDate"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_3"
    android:text="User Name"
    android:layout_below="@id/commentText"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="@dimen/normal_textsize" />
```